# appear images in viewport and disappear if not in viewport

Tags: jquery

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFeqH/424/) it appear once you scroll into it but how to make it disappear when its out of its viewport?

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);

        }

    }); 

});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that will help you in this kind of cases is a diagram of every element and every possible situation.

[image]

So, an element will be inside viewport if

If you want to check if it's fully visible

- `ot3 >= st`
- **and** `ot2 < st+wh`

Or if you want to check if it's at least partially visible/gone

- `ot1+h1 > st`
- **and** `ot3+h3 < st+wh`

An element will be outside of viewport if

- `ot1+h1 < st`
- **or** `ot2 > st+wh`

Being

- `ot1`, `ot2`, `ot3` `offset().top`
- `h1`, `h2`, `h3` `outerHeight()`
- `st` `$(window).scrollTop()`
- `wh` `$(window).height()`

Of course, you don't need to check both.

```
var elemTop=$(this).offset().top;
var elemHeight=$(this).outerHeight();
var scrollTop=$(window).scrollTop();
var winHeight=$(window).height();
if(elemTop>=scrollTop&&elemTop<scrollTop+winHeight) {
    //fade in
} else {
    //fade out
}
```

The same for horizontal scroll with widths and left offsets.

Use `offset()` instead of `position()` since the last one is relative to the element's parent.

And, based on your fiddler, use `stop()` before the animations to stop the current animation before starting a new one. Otherwise, if the user scrolls up and down fast, your objects will start to blink, because jQuery will complete each animation before starting the new animations issued.

Comment: this **Offset top+height < scroll** is `Offset top = .offset().top` + `height = .height()` < `scroll = .scrollTop()` ?

Comment: It seems I still cant figure it out can you please elaborate it? please

Comment: I might have made a mistake. Updated answer and added explanations.